# Manipulating neighborhood polygons using the Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, google-maps-api-2

Google maps does a very good job highliting the neoghborhood boundaries polygons:

[image]

The underlying polygon data is very good. It's definitely better than Foursquare's Quattroshapes.

Since I don't think there's a way to extract this data from Google, I thought that maybe it would be possible to show / highlight and manipulate these polygons as first class objects *inside* Google Maps using the Google Maps Javascript API?

What I would like to do is i.e highlight only a subset of the neighbourhood polygons per city, change their fill colors based on my own data, etc.

Another option would be to get the polygon data from Google and draw the polygons myself, but I'm pretty sure it's not really available. Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot get the information directly through the JavaScript API. If you can find KML data online (or make some yourself), it can be loaded through `google.maps.KmlLayer`.

It is pretty easy to make KML layers in Google Earth. So if you only need 1 city, it may be a good time investment to make.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Getting the neighborhood polygon data is a tough job. There's not a lot available, apart from Foursquare's quattroshapes, but it doesn't have the same quality as Google's. I thought that maybe the js API would allow me to show these polygons programmatically, since I don't have access to the polygon data itself. Hopefully Google will release/provide a way to access this data someday.

Comment: By the way, I edited the question to make it a bit more clear. Thanks for replying, again.